# TYPO3 using element chooser

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is there a way to use the element Chooser from other Backend extension as well?

I have a custom extension with a path value, at the moment I have to fill the input manually with copy paste. What I want is to select the files uploaded with filelist.

[image]

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you want to include [FAL](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/UsingFal/Index.html) here is an example from docs.typo3.org

Comment: for example:
[fal-in-typo3-extensions-verwenden](http://t3-developer.com/ext-programmierung/techniken-in-extensions/fal-in-typo3-extensions-verwenden/)

[fal-in-einer-eigenen-extbasefluid-extension-einsetzen](http://keinerweiss.de/755-typo3-fal-in-einer-eigenen-extbasefluid-extension-einsetzen.html)

[gist.github.com/](https://gist.github.com/maddy2101/5668835)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "element chooser"? if you mean any field in a record like tt_content or pages, then yes.

Take a look at the Configuration module > TCA > find the field you want copy its behaviour and use that in your extension as well.

Btw: 6.2 is EOL! See https://typo3.com/our-services/extended-support/ for details if you need an Extended LTS for that, otherwise please upgrade to 7.6 or 8.7

Comment: I've added two screenshots what I want to use in my extension. Thanks for the hint with EOL. I know. parallel working on migrating to typo3 8 ;)